# Windows Phone 8.1 - Creating template and using it in many places?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I have a scenario where I need to create template and use it in many places.

for example :

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
<TextBlock  Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="12 12 12 6"/>
<Border Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="2" Width="170" Margin="12 0 0 12"/>
<Border Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="2" Width="170" Margin="12 0 0 12"/>
```

I tried some thing like this:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Key="specificationTemplate1">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
       <TextBlock  Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="12 12 12 6"/>
        <Border Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="2" Width="170" Margin="12 0 0 12"/>
        <Border Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="2" Width="170" Margin="12 0 0 12"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPresenter>
```

---

```
Grid grdSpecificationTemplate = (App.Current.Resources["specificationTemplate1"] as ContentPresenter).Content as Grid;
MainGird.Children.Add(grdSpecificationTemplate);
```

The problem I am facing is, first time it is working fine and when I go back and navigate again it's throwing exception "The element is already a child of another element".

Please suggest me Is it a right way to do or Is there any other way.

PS : I want to create some hundred templates like this, so I can't go with User Control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you navigate again do you check `if(MainGird.Children.Contains(grdSpecificationTemplate))` ? That might solve the problem. If it is already added you don't have to add ir again.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. Define your "template" as a `ControlTeplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="specificationTemplate1">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
    <TextBlock  Foreground="Black" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="12 12 12 6"/>
    <Border Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="2" Width="170" Margin="12 0 0 12"/>
    <Border Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="2" Width="170" Margin="12 0 0 12"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can simply use it as a `ContentControl`

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource specificationTemplate1" />
```

Or on code

```
var c = new ContentControl
{
    Template = (ControlTemplate)App.Current.Resources["specificationTemplate1"]
}
```

Comment: This wont solve my problem. ControlTemplate and DataTemplate can only be used with generic items. How can I get the content inside the Template i.e Grid programatically ?

Comment: You can use binding inside the ControlTemplate and set DataContext for the ContentControl you the create. But reading this I think creating a UserControl would be better for you.

Comment: Thats what I initially mentioned, I can't go with UserControl as there is need of more than 100 templates in which I will end up with 100 pages of UserControl.

Comment: In that case, no matter what you use the performance will be poor. Consider drawing do a Canvas.